# Show that $\int_0^x\left\{\int_0^v\left\{\int_0^uf(t)\ dt\right\}du\right\}dv={1\over 2}\int_0^x(x-t)^2f(t)dt$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

How to show that:

> $$\int_0^x\left\{\int_0^v\left\{\int_0^uf(t)\ dt\right\}du\right\}dv={1\over 2}\int_0^x(x-t)^2f(t)dt$$

I am not getting which property to use. Thank you for any help.

Comment: Change the order of integration.

Comment: If you draw the solid that is described by the integral in the LHS, we will get it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use integration by parts multiple times.

Let $F_0(x) = f(x)$ and for $ n > 0$ let $F_n(x) = \int_0^x F_{n-1}(u) du$. We need to show $F_3(x) = \dfrac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{x} (x-t)^2f(t)dt.$

$$
\begin{align}
F_3(x) &= \int_{0}^{x} F_2(u) du\\
 &= \int_{0}^{x} \frac{d}{du} (u - x) F_2(u) du\\ &= \left[ (u - x) F_2(u) \right]_{0}^{x} - \int_{0}^{x} (u-x)F_1(u)du\\ &= - \int_{0}^{x} (u-x)F_1(u)du\\
&= -\dfrac{1}{2} \int_{0}^{x} \frac{d}{du}(u-x)^2F_1(u)du\\
&= -\dfrac{1}{2}\left( \left[ (u-x)^2 F_1(x) \right]_{0}^{x} - \int_{0}^{x} (u-x)^2f(u)du\right)\\ &= \dfrac{1}{2}\int_{0}^{x}(u-x)^2f(u)du 
\end{align}  
$$

Answer (score 3):

It's a standard result obtained via integration by parts. Note that LHS denotes a function $F(x) $ such that $F'''(x) =f(x) $ and $$F(0)=F'(0)=F''(0)=0$$ Use intermediary functions $$G(x) =\int_{0}^{x}f(t)\,dt,\,H(x)=\int_{0} ^{x} G(t) \, dt$$ and note that $$F(x) =\int_{0}^{x}H(t)\,dt$$

Answer (score 2):

**Hint.** Sketch a diagram on $u,v,t$-axes. Change the order of integration.

Comment: Can you please explain a bit more?

Comment: Have you tried sketching a region ? Do you know how to change the order of integration ?

Comment: Can't we do it analytically?

Answer (score 2):

Just change the order of integration, after affirming that Fubini's or Tonelli's Theorem holds.

$$\int_0^x\int_0^v\int_0^u f(t)\ \operatorname d t\ \operatorname d u\ \operatorname d v \\ = \iiint_{0\leqslant t\leqslant u\leqslant v\leqslant x}f(t)\ \operatorname d(t,u,v) \\ = \int_0^x f(t)\int_t^x\int_u^x\ \operatorname dv\ \operatorname du\ \operatorname dt$$

Confirm that the inner two integrals evaluates as required. $$\int_t^x\int_u^x  \operatorname dv\ \operatorname du~=~ \tfrac 12(x-t)^2$$

Answer (score 1):

A "constructive proof"

Let the $n-$th order (in the OP it is 3rd order) initial value problem
$$
x^{(n)}=f, \quad x(t_0)=x'(t_0)=\cdots=x^{(n-1)}(t_0)=0. \tag{1}
$$
This is equivalent to the system
$$
x_1'=x_2,\,x_2'=x_3,\ldots,x_{n-1}'=x_n,\,x_n'=f, \quad x_1(t_0)=\cdots=x_n(t_0)=0.
$$
or
$$
\boldsymbol{x}'=A\boldsymbol{x}, \quad \boldsymbol{x}(t_0)=0. \tag{2}
$$
where 
$$
A=\left(\begin{matrix}0 & 1& 0 &\cdots&\cdots& 0 \\
&0 &1 & \\
&&0& 1 \\ &&&&\ddots
\\ &&&&0&1\\&&&&&0\end{matrix}\right)
$$
Note that what we are looking for is an expression for $x_1(t)$, which is going to be the solution of $(1)$.

**Solution of the IVP.**
$$
\boldsymbol{x}(t)=\mathrm{e}^{(t-t_0)A}\boldsymbol{x}(t-t_0)+\int_{t_0}^t\mathrm{e}^{(t-s)A}\boldsymbol{f}(s)\,ds=\int_{t_0}^t\mathrm{e}^{(t-s)A}\boldsymbol{f}(s)\,ds,
$$
where
$$
\mathrm{e}^{tA}=\left(\begin{matrix}1 & t& \frac{t^2}{2} &\cdots&\cdots& \frac{t^{n-1}}{{(n-1)!}} \\
&1 &t &\frac{t^2}{2!}& \\
&&1& t \\ &&&&\ddots
\\ &&&&1&t\\&&&&&1\end{matrix}\right)\qquad\text{and}\qquad \boldsymbol{f}=\left(\begin{array}{c}0\\0\\ \vdots\\ 0\\ f\end{array}\right).
$$
Clearly
$$
x_1(t)=\int_{t_0}^t\frac{(t-s)^{n-1}\,f(s)\,ds}{(n-1)!}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Taylor-Lagrange formula with the Integral Remainder to the left side of the equation. The derivatives evaluated at 0 will be equal to zero. This gives the desired result directly.

Comment: This formula : $$f(x) = f(a) +f'(a)(x-a) + \frac{f''(a)}{2!}(x-a)^2 +\cdots
\frac{f^{(k)}(a)}{k!}(x-a)^k +\int_a^x f^{(k+1)}(t)\frac{(x-t)^k}{k!}\,dt$$

Comment: Why should the the derivatives at $0$ be Zero?

Comment: The integral of any function between $0$ and $0$ is $0$. Apply the formula for $a=0$.

Comment: Don't use the formula for f, but for the left side of the equation.